# How do I reference functions in TinyMCE 'init_instance_callback'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using WordPress's `wp_editor` function to setup a TinyMCE instance. I want to add some extra functionality to TinyMCE using some jQuery functions, but it seems that I'm limited to using TinyMCE functions for things such as `focus`, `change` and `blur`.

When I set up TinyMCE this way, I'm basically forced to use the `init_instance_callback` property.

**PHP**

```
$default_settings = array(  
    'media_buttons' => false,
    'quicktags' => false,

    'tinymce' => array(
        'init_instance_callback' => 'function(editor) { // Forced to use JS in PHP...
                editor.on("focus", function(ed) {
                    tinyMCEFocus(ed);
                });
            }'
    )
);
```

I have a different file where I want to handle TinyMCE JavaScript, as I don't want to write all my JavaScript in the PHP  file where I call `wp_editor()`.

In my `editor.on("focus", function(ed) {` I placed a function that's inside my external JS file, in which I've also defined jQuery.

**JS**

```
( function( $ ) {

    var tinyMCEFocus = function(ed) {           
        console.log('Do stuff with jQuery if this works');
    }

} )( jQuery );
```

But somehow, when calling this function, it simply does not work and gives me an error:

> (index):401 Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCEFocus is not defined

Honestly, so far using TinyMCE for custom stuff has been a distaster, but maybe I'm doing something wrong? Is there a better way to handle this type of thing? And if not, why isn't my function working?

Comment: You could have probably also run `editor.tinyMCEFocus(ed)` instead of `tinyMCEFocus(ed)`. When you don't have the `editor` defined, the browser engine will look for identifier `tinyMCEFocus` in local closure and fail to find your intended function.

Answer (score 0):

Yet again, answering my own question mere minutes after posting it.

I found out you have to give the function a "global" scope by assigning it to the window. This also allowed me to simply pass a function to `init_instance_callback`.

```
'tinymce' => array(
    'init_instance_callback' => 'customTinyMCEFunctions'
)
```

And in JavaScript.

```
( function( $ ) {
    window.customTinyMCEFunctions= function(editor) {
        // Do stuff
    }
} )( jQuery );
```